# TensorFlow: improve accuracy on training data

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I am experimenting with TensorFlow. One of my first tries consists on learning one of the features based on the data. Let's say my data is composed on the following values:

```
35, 2, 3, 4, 19, 31, 7, 9, 34, 10, 33, 12, 59, 6, 14, 31, 13
...
35, 4, 7, 14, 9, 3, 17, 19, 42, 11, 3, 1, 53, 12, 17, 30, 15
```

I would like to predict the value of the last feature, in the example it is going to be the values 13 for the first row and 15 for the last row.

I have around 10000 rows of data. I've written the following model using TensorFlow(I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vq2nnJ4g6N0)):

```
    W0 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([nb_attributes, 25]))
    B0 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([25]))

    W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([25, 30], stddev=0.1))
    B1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([30]))

    W2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([30, 70], stddev=0.1))
    B2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([70]))

    W3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([70, 150], stddev=0.1))
    B3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([150]))

    W4 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([150, 75], stddev=0.1))
    B4 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([75]))

    W5 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([75, 54], stddev=0.1))
    B5 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([54]))

    # placeholder for input and output
    x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, nb_attributes])
    Y_ = tf.placeholder("float", [None,54])

    XX = tf.reshape(x, [-1, nb_attributes])
    Y1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(XX, W0) + B0)
    Y2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(Y1, W1) + B1)
    Y3 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(Y2, W2) + B2)
    Y4 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(Y3, W3) + B3)
    Y5 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(Y4, W4) + B4)


    # learned output
    Ylogits = tf.matmul(Y5, W5) + B5
    Y = tf.nn.softmax(Ylogits)

    cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=Ylogits, labels=Y_)
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)*100

    train_step = tf.train.ProximalGradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)
```

The train step is as follows:

```
    for i in range(100):
        batch_xs, batch_ys = get_train_events()
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, Y_: batch_ys})

        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(Y,1), tf.argmax(Y_,1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))

        test_data_evs, test_data_out = batch_xs, batch_ys
        current_accuracy = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: test_data_evs, Y_: test_data_out})

        print 'Current Accuracy {}'.format(current_accuracy)
```

Please, note that I am using the same data for training than for testing. I am aware that it is not the approach to follow but I am doing on this way because I've found that the accuracy on the test data was so bad that I decided to know what was the accuracy on the training data. As far as I understand it is supposed that the accuracy on the training data after testing must be close to 100%, isn't it?

However, I cannot improve the accuracy to more the 60%. I tried the following:

- Give the data using different strategies
- Using different training optimizer from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/train)
- Change the net architecture
- Using dropout approach

The only step that shown some progress has been to provide testing data randomly in batch of size N. In such case, I managed to move the accuracy from 60 to 64%. I was wondering whether I am applying a wrong approach or committing some stupid or naive error. Any thought in respect of the issue is going to very much appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance!

EDIT 1: For the sake of completing the question I managed to solve quite well the problem by using the k-neighbour algorithm. [This code](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/2_BasicModels/nearest_neighbor.py) have helped in my case.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to predict the last value in a series of values, correct? The assumption being that the series of values offers some idea of what value is coming next? I think you might want to look into recurrent neural networks for this task. I have had some luck on similar tasks with the LSTM and GRU network structures.

Comment: @Engineero: yes, you got it right! I am going to read, learn and then apply those networks! Thats a lot!

Comment: Is this a *series* of values, or independent columns?  For instance, if you reversed the order of all columns but the last, would the prediction be equally valid?  If the order is not important, then RNN isn't the best choice for you.

Comment: Independent columns, actually the data comes out of a dictionary data structure. However, I could fix the order and so be able to apply LSTM and GRU, isn't it?

Comment: I found out that digging on my data that the neural net performance improves when having less categories to classify on. I've changed the number of categories from 52 to 3 and the accuracy rose from 60 to 90%. Does it have sense? The only explanation I made up is that the probabilities are better distributed when fewer categories are considered.

Comment: First of all decide, whether your problem is classification, regression or time-series and then think about the solution.